# In device tree, can't understand 'ranges' property of PCIe root complex node

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree, pci-e

For example in linux-5.15.68's arch/arm64/boot/dts/ti/k3-am64-main.dtsi,

```
&cbass_main {
    ... skip ...
    pcie0_rc: pcie@f102000 {
        compatible = "ti,am64-pcie-host", "ti,j721e-pcie-host";
        reg = <0x00 0x0f102000 0x00 0x1000>,
              <0x00 0x0f100000 0x00 0x400>,
              <0x00 0x0d000000 0x00 0x00800000>,
              <0x00 0x68000000 0x00 0x00001000>;
        reg-names = "intd_cfg", "user_cfg", "reg", "cfg";
  ... skip ...   
        #address-cells = <3>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
   ...skip ...
        msi-map = <0x0 &gic_its 0x0 0x10000>;
        ranges = <0x01000000 0x00 0x68001000  0x00 0x68001000  0x00 0x0010000>,
             <0x02000000 0x00 0x68011000  0x00 0x68011000  0x00 0x7fef000>;
        dma-ranges = <0x02000000 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x00000010 0x0>;
    };
};
```

the 'ranges' property says

- IO space starting at address 0x68001000 with size 64KiB is mapped to the parent bus address 0x68001000.
- a 32 bit memory address space starting with address 0x68011000 and size 0x7fef000 is mapped to parent bus address 0x68011000.

The device tree document says these addresses are all physical.
What I can't understand is :

I know the BIOS will set the BAR addresses during the enumeration process. This is allocating the endpoint's function to a certain PCIe bus address and I guess setting BAR can be done without this 'ranges' information(it will assign free address range for that device according to the device's need). By the time linux kernel later reads this 'ranges' property, the BIOS (or bootloader) has already assigned different PCIe address to that device. Then, how is this 'ranges' property used by the kernel?

Comment: If the system's bootloader has a driver for this PCIe controller in root complex mode then I guess it would use the same mapping as the kernel. (It would probably be specified in some hardware reference manual for the SoC somewhere.) But the bootloader could just leave it up to the kernel to do everything related to the root complex.

Comment: I tried to find what the bootloader does with that 'range' property but couldn't yet. And I found in 'PCI bus bindings to : IEEE Std 1275-1994 standard for Boot firmware'  document, this 'range' property is for pci-to-pci bridge (and RC contains bridge property I understand). So if an address range is behind that bridge, that should be included in the range property.

Comment: and  '6. Probing PCI-to-PCI bridges' says (after setting the bridge parameters during the scan) "After setting the Memory Base, Memory Limit, I/O Base and I/O Limit registers, create a "ranges" property that
represents the Memory and I/O mappings that have been established." . So it looks like this parameter is set by the bootloader (or kernel?).

Comment: I suppose that can be used as a hint of what memory or IO space is available to assign during enumeration... if that was meant to be used for PCIe, nothing else will be using that memory